# Sync Google Sheet to multiple other sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I created 2 sheets one contains date ranges(Dates) and the other contains the core template(Template). I am then running 2 app scrip functions. The first makes copies of my core template based on the date range in the "Dates" sheet. The second renames each copied template to the date listed in sequential order. All works fine but I know I will have to make updates to the core template in the near future.
Is there a way to link all copies to the core template so then when I make changes to the core template I can run a separate sync script that will push the changes to all the other copies?
BTW I am no app script developer! I literally pieced this from Googling things and GitHub.

[image: Template]

[image: Dates]

[image: App Script]

Comment: Hi. I recall another question asked in the last few weeks that bears a close similarity to this question. Did you see that earlier question? There's no "automatic" linage, but depending on the nature of the changes), one would think that it would be possible to write a script that would add the changes to all the sheets. If you are not currently an "app script developer", you would need to develop those skills in order to create that script, OR (and this is more sensible) you would contract someone to write it for you.

Comment: Hey Tedinoz, 
Thank your for responding. I did not see that previous question you are referring to as I had posted this question elsewhere and then had it moved by an admin to this site. I am not an "app script developer" and currently what I pieced together works but I wanted to jump ahead of the curve and set it up for future changes.

Comment: Very sensible. Bear in mind, volunteers don't know the structure of your template or data sheets, nor the nature of any template changes and the effect on existing sheets; and, presumably, it would be unacceptable to over-write any existing data. Having said that, how's this for a _what-if_ idea: take an existing data sheet, copy the data on the sheet, "copy/paste" the revised template to the sheet, copy existing data back into the sheet. If you could do that manually, then it could be done by a script.

Comment: FWIW, one thing that you will have to do is loop through your list of data sheets and do stuff in each of them. So, you might start your own code development with how to "get" that list of sheet names from the "Dates" sheet; how to use the list to progressively work through each sheet ("loop through the sheets");do something in each sheet (such as, say, get the value in Cell "A1" and display the result to screen).